# How do I add a node field widget to a custom form?

Tags: 8, entities

I added a number of fields to a node content type in Drupal 8. I want to create a custom form and add the field widget form (the one used during node creation) to this form.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question, I ended up using the following:

```
<?php
//Create an empty representative entity
$node = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node')->create(array(
                'type' => 'article'
            )
        );

//Get the EntityFormDisplay (i.e. the default Form Display) of this content type
$entity_form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_form_display')
                                        ->load('node.article.default');

$form['#parents'] = []; // Mandatory, otherwise the widget class throws an error

//Get the body field widget and add it to the form
if ($widget = $entity_form_display->getRenderer('body')) { //Returns the widget class
  $items = $node->get('body'); //Returns the FieldItemsList interface
  $items->filterEmptyItems();
  $form['body'] = $widget->form($items, $form, $form_state); //Builds the widget form and attach it to your form
  $form['body']['#access'] = $items->access('edit');
}
```

see [EntityFormDisplay::buildForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity%21EntityFormDisplay.php/function/EntityFormDisplay%3A%3AbuildForm/8.2.x)

Comment: $form['#parents'] needs to be set to something or you'll get an exception - an empty array will do.

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work without setting $form['#parents'] = array(); beforehand. Maybe add this to your answer?

Comment: I'm using this for a field on a node where the user doesn't have permission to edit the node. It's specifically a paragraph field and it is not being fully shown in the custom form. How can I alter the permission so the user has full access to the field, or do I need to allow them to edit the node?

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use this code

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
        'type' => 'article'
      ]);
$form_state->set('node', $entity );       
$form_display = EntityFormDisplay::collectRenderDisplay($entity, 'default');
$form_display->buildForm($entity, $form, $form_state);
```

[I found this solution here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-09-05/drupal-8-equivalent-to-field_attach#comment-11278197)

Comment: Drupal::entityManager() is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This comment is for people who want to make the code work for Drupal 8.9/ 9