# Save paragraph widget data in custom form

Tags: forms

I am adding a node field widget in a custom form as [described here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203282/how-do-i-add-a-node-field-widget-to-a-custom-form) and my code is:

```
$site_settings_node = Node::load($node_id);
$entity_form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_form_display')
  ->load('node.node_type.default');
if ($widget = $entity_form_display->getRenderer('field_my_field')) {
  $items = $site_settings_node->get('field_my_field');
  $items->filterEmptyItems();
  $form['#parents'] = array();
  $form['custom_form_field'] = $widget->form($items, $form, $form_state);
}
```

How do I update the paragraph field values in my submit handler? Is there something like the below that I can do?

```
$widget = $entity_form_display->getRenderer('field_my_field')
$widget->submit($items, $form, $form_state);
```

Comment: I've seen your [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203282/how-do-i-add-a-node-field-widget-to-a-custom-form?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment344109_203457) on the linked answer. Instead of this hack I think a better approach would be a form mode containing this node field and control access with a module like [Form Mode Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution via [this article](https://www.webomelette.com/how-render-entity-field-widgets-inside-custom-form-drupal-8). Though for the solution to work specifically for the paragraph field, I had to add a patch for an issue [discussed here](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2901390).

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#parents'] = array();

  $node_id = 1; // Some node
  $entity = Node::load($node_id);
  $form_state->set('entity', $entity);

  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityFormDisplayInterface $form_display */
  $form_display = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_form_display')->load('node.node_type.default');
  $form_state->set('form_display', $form_display);

  foreach ($form_display->getComponents() as $name => $component) {
    $widget = $form_display->getRenderer($name);
    if (!$widget) {
      continue;
    }
    $items = $entity->get($name);
    $items->filterEmptyItems();
    $form[$name] = $widget->form($items, $form, $form_state);
    $form[$name]['#access'] = $items->access('edit');
    $form[$name]['#weight'] = $component['weight'];
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'submit',
  );
  return $form;
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityFormDisplayInterface $form_display */
  $form_display = $form_state->get('form_display');
  $entity = $form_state->get('entity');
  $form_display->extractFormValues($entity, $form, $form_state);
  $entity->save();
}
```